# Web resource not found

Tags: .net-4.0, webforms

I'm having some trouble with web resources, I keep getting the error:

> Web resource
>   'EMP.WebHelpers.Scripts.CostSearchControl.ascx.js'
>   was not found.was not found.

My settings are as follows:

Assembly name: EMP.WebHelpers.dll

AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
[assembly: WebResource("EMP.WebHelpers.Scripts.SupplierAtoZControl.ascx.js", "application/x-javascript")]
[assembly: WebResource("EMP.WebHelpers.Scripts.CostSearchControl.ascx.js", "application/x-javascript")]
```

The scripts are held in a folder < projectroot >\Scripts\ and both scripts in this folder are set to have the build action of embedded resource.

And when I point reflector at the assembly It finds two resources, called:

```
EMP.WebHelpers.Scripts.CostSearchControl.ascx.js
```

and

```
EMP.WebHelpers.Scripts.SupplierAtoZControl.ascx.js
```

Finally to add the script to my control I call

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptResource(Page, GetType(), "EMP.WebHelpers.Scripts.CostSearchControl.ascx.js");
```

So to my eyes it all looks like it should work, but it doesn't, what am I missing?